# warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, generics, netbeans, jlist

I'm getting this warning from the compiler which does not make sense at all (at least to me).  It basically wants me to assign a Type to DefaultListModel which is a object type by itself!  I'm getting heaps of this warnings all through my code!

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...\filename.java:345:warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: DefaultListModel
DefaultListModel lm = (DefaultListModel) jList_DataSetList.getModel();
missing type arguments for generic class DefaultListModel<E>
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class DefaultListModel
```

This is another one which I have no idea where is comes from!

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...\filename.java:897: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: JList
private javax.swing.JList jList_DataSetList;
missing type arguments for generic class JList<E>
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class JList
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Java 7, `DefaultListModel` is a generic type, like `List`, `Set`, etc. It expects a type : `DefaultListModel<SomeClass>` instead of the raw `DefaultListModel`.

This allows to work in a more type-safe way, because you won't be able to insert a String into a list model which is supposed to contain Integer instances. And you won't have to cast to Integer when getting an element from the model.

The same is true for `JList` which is also now a `JList` of Strings or a `JList` of Integers, instead of being a raw `JList`.

Read the [tutorial about generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html), and have a look at the [javadoc of DefaultListModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the accurate and spot on answer!  I was referencing from the old api documentation and didn't know the one you pointed me into ever existed!  You saved my day!

Comment: Since I contributed that patch to OpenJDK I blogged about it here: http://puces-blog.blogspot.com/2009/11/news-swing-generics-openjdk-jlist-patch.html

Answer (score 3):

Try   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

This is a particularly awful default when working with reflection or when working with interfaced methods where the exact type of the generic object is supposed to be hidden.  I started changing my Class references to Class when I remembered @Suppress.

Answer (score 1):

And if someone is looking for these warnings in the NetBeans IDE (7.0.1) generated code (for JList etc.) and you don't know, how to correct it, follow these steps:

1. Go to GUI editor (matisse builder).
2. Select (click on) the component (JList, etc.)
3. Go to Properties window, to Code tab
4. Write the <Something> into Type Parametres property. Of course, the "Something" would be String, or your object...